# Forgetting Cache using Regular expression laravel

Tags: laravel, caching, redis

I am using using laravel and Redis driver to store my cache and I keep my keys scoped to the current tenant. Below is how I set my cache; where `$tenant` is the current tenant.

```
$department_count = Cache::remember('dep_count:'.$tenant, 60 * 60 * 24, function () use ($tenant) {
       return Department::where('is_active', 'yes')->where('tenantID', $tenant)->count();
});
```

So on switch school, I want to clear all the cache for current tenant using `cache::forget()` but I don't know how to do that.

I've tried `Cache::forget('*:'.$tenant)` but it doesn't seem to work. Any help on how to go about it is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want group cache and remove only specific group of cache you can use tags.

Please read [this](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/cache#cache-tags). It will be helpful

```
Cache::tags(['tag_'.$tenant])->remember('dep_count:'.$tenant, 60 * 60 * 24, function () use ($tenant) {
       return Department::where('is_active', 'yes')->where('tenantID', $tenant)->count();
});
```

For remove

```
Cache::tags(['tag_'.$tenant])->flush();
```

Comment: This will work for me, I didn't know about tags. Thank you very much @Aro